# How to enable Nutch follow http redirect?

Tags: java, web-crawler, nutch

During my crawling, there is a page redirecting to 404 error, but when i use "readdb" command, the status of the page is still 302 instead of 404.

Then i looked up the configuration file, and i found option "http.redirect.max". I have already configure "http.redirect.max" for 3, and recrawled the page, but the status of it is still 302.

After i read the source code, i found something like:

```
Response response = getResponse(u, datum, false);
```

In method "getProtocolOutput" of HttpBase.java. After i changed "false" to "true" and recompiled nutch, the function works.

So i wonder is this a correct way of enabling nutch to follow redirects? Will this modification leads to some other error while crawling?

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this case, Nutch is working properly `http.redirect.max` controls if the redirect is followed immediately or if it should be queued for a next round.

If you crawl one URL (A) which contains a redirect to a 404, the first URL still exists with a 30x state, it's the second URL (B) that has a 404 response. From Nutch side, there are two different URLs (which makes sense).

I haven't tested your change (with other scenarios), but if you have a similar case, let's say that page A redirects to a different page C (which is not a 404), in this case, would you expect that the content of page C to be linked to the URL of A and totally ignore the URL of C?

In the browser, this is usually how we perceive it, but underneath there are two different requests/URLs.